# Patternmatching in Haskell with Either type

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, interpreter, either

I try to patternmatch on the Either type but I get an error. Why does the following work

```
patternMaster :: Either a b -> b  
patternMaster (Right a) = a
patternMaster (Left b) = b
```

with `patternMaster (Right a)`

whereas I get the following output when I apply the function with its type mentioned just below:

```
Arithmetic.hs:101:26: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `b' with actual type `a'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          patternMaster :: forall a b. Either a b -> b
        at Arithmetic.hs:99:1-32
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          patternMaster :: forall a b. Either a b -> b
        at Arithmetic.hs:99:1-32
    * In the expression: b
      In an equation for `patternMaster': patternMaster (Left b) = b
    * Relevant bindings include
        b :: a (bound at Arithmetic.hs:101:21)
        patternMaster :: Either a b -> b (bound at Arithmetic.hs:100:1)
```

```
-- -----------Types
initEnvironment :: Env
initEnvironment = \_v -> Nothing

-- --------Function
evalErr :: Exp -> Env -> Either ArithError Integer
evalErr (Cst e1) _ = Right e1 
evalErr (Div e1 e2) env = 
                          case evalErr e2 env of
                            Left az -> Left az 
                            Right az -> 
                              if az == 0 
                                then Left EDivZero 
                              else 
                                case (evalErr e1 env) of
                                Left b -> Left b
                                Right b -> Right (b `div` az)
```

Shouldn't it be the same?

Comment: Your error message doesn't match the code you've shown.

Comment: The `case` expression in your error is mistyped. `a` could be an `ArithError` or an `Integer`, so what's the type of the `case` expression itself supposed to be?

Comment: `patternMaster` *only* applies to sum of a type with itself; that's not the case with `Either ArithError Integer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this demo function:

```
patternMaster :: Either b b -> b  
patternMaster (Right a) = a
patternMaster (Left a) = a
```

the input has to have the same type for the left and right alternatives, and `patternMaster something` has that type as well. E.g.

- if `something` is `Either Integer Integer` then `patternMaster something` is `Integer`
- if `something` is `Either Integer String` then `patternMaster something` does not compile

Meanwhile your real code:

```
something =
    case (evalErr (Cst 4) initEnvironment) of
      (Left a) -> a
      (Right a) -> a
```

what is the type of the case expression? If `evalErr` evaluates, then it's `Integer`. If `evalErr` returns an error, then it's `ArithError`. Those are incompatible types - there's no valid type for `something`.

If you wanted to say it could be either `Integer` or `ArithError`, then you wouldn't have written this case statement and the overall type would be `Either ArithError Integer`

---

At *some point* your program has to care about whether it's an ArithError or an Integer and run different code for each one. That's where you put the case statement. E.g. if you want to convert either both of them to strings, you could write:

```
showMaster :: (Show a, Show b) => Either a b -> String
showMaster (Right x) = show x
showMaster (Left x) = show x
```

noting that each `show` calls a different function so it's different code, but both of them return strings so the return value of showMaster is always a string.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying and agree with it besides. But what I want to do is to unpack the values a and b with the auxillary function patternMaster such that for each pattern I want to match in `evalErr` I can apply the patternMaster rather than the case ugly case-unpacking that I have attempted so far. But how do I go about doing that. Even if I change the type to `patternMaster :: Either a b -> b` it will of course still be incompatible types as you are saying. I guess that is only possible due to the if- expression within the case expression in the `evalErr`

Comment: @Piskator What do you want the result to be if the evaluation is an Integer? What do you want the result to be if it's an ArithError?

Comment: If it is an integer the function should just return the integer (e.g "5"). If it is an ArithError i want the function to return one of several instances of the type ArithError (e.g. DivByZero) each of which I will declare in my type library.

Comment: @Piskator And what should be the type of something that is either an ArithError (e.g. DivByZero) or an Integer (e.g. 5)?

Comment: A maybe type!? Or an Either type, which is why I have tried with the Either type. I am not sure I follow you.

Comment: @Piskator Okay so you do see that to have something of type `ArithError` or `Integer` you can use `Either ArithError Integer`. The problem is that you are trying to take this value whose type is `Either ArithError Integer` and jam it into a variable of type `Integer` which makes no sense because what would go in the variable if it was an ArithError? You can't put an ArithError into an Integer variable.

Comment: @Piskator `patternMaster :: Either b b -> b` says that you can pass an argument like `Either Integer Integer` and the return type is `Integer`. Or you can pass `Either String String` and the return type is `String`. That works. `Either ArithError Integer` doesn't work because it's not the same type on both sides whereas the declaration of patternMaster says it is the same type on both sides.

Comment: That is also how I understood the solution you proposed above. But what I don't see is how to go about it such that I can avoid the 'ugly' case expression and embedded if-expression in the `evalErr` if I can't use `patternMaster` or any function with patternmatchin for that sake to 'unpack' the values within the `Left a` or `Right a`.

Comment: @Piskator the way to 'unpack' the values is to write `case (evalErr (Cst 4) initEnvironment) of (Left a) ->` whatever you want the answer to be if it's left ` (Right a) -> ` whatever you want the answer to be as it's right - exactly as you wrote - except that both sides have to have the same type! Some part of your program is going to handle the aritherror and the integer in similar ways (like printing them both, so both sides are `IO ()`). That part has to unpack it. You can't unpack early.

Comment: Can't I use a do-expression or something else, that is more simple?

Comment: @Piskator At some point in your program your program is going to care about whether this is an ArithError or an Integer. Please describe what your program will do differently depending on whether it's an ArithError or an Integer.

Comment: It is not going to do anything different. As I have tried to explain the output for the user should either be an integer or an ArithError. I want different cases of the latter for the different patternmatches of `errEval` however: DivByZero, NegPower , IntegerMaximumReached etc.
What interests me however is the intermediate step to be able to unpack these in a nice way, as I have tried to do with the patternMaster.

Comment: @Piskator So it is going to do something different, then. In one case it outputs an Integer, and in the other case it outputs an ArithError. Perhaps you want to convert both to `String` and then you can print the string? Or you can convert both to a printing operation `IO ()`

Comment: I Shall post a new question where I try to do that. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Piskator e.g. `showEither :: (Show a, Show b) => Either a b -> String` `showEither (Left x) = show x` `showEither (Right x) = show x`